# "manage brand terms" option in GA

Tags: google-analytics

As of today I have a new setting in one of my Google Analytics Accounts in Admin->Channel Groupings which is called "Manage Brand Terms" (see screenshot). I have not found documentation for this feature. Obviously this has to do with search, but from the sparse info in the tooltips - "*We'll use this to classify your queries*" - I do not quite understand what this does or how to use the setting.  The settings don't seem to be reflected anywhere in the reports.

If anybody knows what this is about and is willing to share I'd be grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This explains everything:

http://searchengineland.com/google-analytics-now-separates-brand-non-brand-ppc-traffic-195281

I wish I saw this in my account, but I do not.  :-(

Comment: I had already figured it out by now, but still thank you :-)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.